# how to keep content aligned at the top

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with an options and answers feature I have. If I select an options which contains an output of some many buttons e.g If I choose option 20, it will display 20 buttons, the problem I am getting i my content drops down a little bit as it creates a space when the table cell increases. My question is simply how can I keep the content aligned near enough the top and not move down if the table cell increases a bit?

Screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

Below is what I attempted but did not work:

```
.option{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:1em;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
}

.noofanswer{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:1em;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
}

.answer{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:1em;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
}
```

Below is the tables:

```
var $options = $("<table class='option'><tbody><tr><td>1. Option Type:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
var $noofanswers = $("<table class='noofanswers'><tbody><tr><td>2. Number of Answers:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
var $answer = $("<table class='answer'><tbody><tr><td>3. Answer:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
```

UPDATE:

```
 var $options = $("<table class='option'><tbody><tr><td class='opt'>1. Option Type:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
    var $noofanswers = $("<table class='noofanswers'><tbody><tr><td class='noofans'>2. Number of Answers:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
    var $answer = $("<table class='answer'><tbody><tr><td class='ans'>3. Answer:</td></tr></tbody></table>");


    var $this, i=0, $row, $cell;
    $('#optionAndAnswer .answers').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if(i%6 == 0) {
            $row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($answer);
            $cell = $("<td/>").appendTo($row);
        }
        var $newBtn = $(("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display:%s;' onclick='btnclick(this, " + gQuestionIndex + ");' />").replace('%s', $this.is(':visible') ? 'inline-block' : 'none')).attr('name', "value[" + gQuestionIndex + "][]").attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class')).attr('id', $this.attr('id') + 'Row');
        $newBtn.appendTo($cell);

        i++;
    });
```

CSS:

```
td.opt{
    vertical-align:top;
    padding-top:1em;
}

td.noofans{
    vertical-align:top;
}

td.ans{
    vertical-align:top;
    padding-bottom:1em;

}

.option{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:1em;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin:0;
}

.noofanswer{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:1em;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin:0;
}

.answer{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:1em;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this CSS for `<td>` elements:

```
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

And here is more specifics. The whole CSS should look like this:

```
* {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.option{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:1em;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
}

.noofanswer{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:1em;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
}

.answer{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:1em;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
}
```

And here is the PHP code with edits to add `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` to the `<table>` tags:

```
var $options = $("<table class='option' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tbody><tr><td>1. Option Type:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
var $noofanswers = $("<table class='noofanswers' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tbody><tr><td>2. Number of Answers:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
var $answer = $("<table class='answer' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tbody><tr><td>3. Answer:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
```

Comment: It still knows the content down a little bit from the top

Comment: cellpadding and cellspacing did not work, it is still adding a space from top. Do I need to include border-spacing and border collapse?

Comment: I include a class .opt in first table td and then included border-spacing 0 and border collapse and still adding the singe space

Comment: Can you update your answer to include a further css so I know what to exactly include in the td and in the table so I don't miss anything out?

Comment: It did not work but can ypu please look at update very quickly, I also included the code where it adds a new table row for every 6 letter buttons displayed.

Comment: Can you give me a yes or no answer if the code showing 6 buttons per row may affect this? I will figure it out myself. Thanks for your help btw :)